# store binary data of media(image/video) received from whatsapp cloud API

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-handling, whatsapp, binary-data

i have to store binary data of which i received from whatsapp cloud api. i am using node js but unable to send the file data using form data

here is reference i have referred https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#example-2

```
function handleMedia(id, number) {
  mediaServiceApi(id).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data.url);
    console.log(res.data.mime_type);
    getMediaData(res.data.url).then((res) => {
      var datafm = new FormData();
      datafm.append("mobile_number", `${number}`);
      datafm.append("category", "1");
      datafm.append("ticket_type", "1");
      datafm.append("subject", "Device not working");
      datafm.append("description", "my device is not working");
      datafm.append("document", res);

      var config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "",
        headers: {
          "Access-Token": "",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          ...datafm.getHeaders(),
        },
        data: datafm,
      };

      axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(
            "this is JSON data of ticket created",
            JSON.stringify(response.data)
          );
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
    let textmsg = `We have registered your query with refrance of a media`;
    textServiceApi(textmsg, number);
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks ok to me... Have you checked if res's value is correct? Do you get any error? What's not working? Can we see the code that receives the formdata, might be a problem there too...?

Comment: Thanks @Salketer for looking into it. "res.data" solved the issue..

Answer (score 0):

in the getMediaData() api call we have to define "responseType" as a "streame" which will get the binary data as a streme format [axios call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGKZv.png) and we have to pass "res.data" instead of just res.
thanks